# Display JSON data using an Angular DataTable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using an Angular DataTable to display data using a JSON array but the data did not display. I think there is an issue with my HTML page. Can you find the issue?

HTML file:

```
   <tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="user in userList">
    <td><a class="green shortinfo" href="javascript:;" ng-click="childInfo(user, $event)" title="Click to view more"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></a></td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.position}}</td>
    <td>{{user.office}}</td>
    <td><div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="edit($index);"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></button>  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn" ng-click="delete();"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button> 
            </div></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is part of the HTML page:

MY JSON data format:

```
$scope.userList = {"InvoiceHeaders":[
{
  "name": "Tiger Nixon",
  "position": "System Architect",
  "salary": "$320,800",
  "start_date": "2011/04/25",
  "office": "Edinburgh",
  "extn": "5421"
},
{
  "name": "Garrett Winters",
  "position": "Accountant",
  "salary": "$170,750",
  "start_date": "2011/07/25",
  "office": "Tokyo",
  "extn": "8422"
}
```

];
}

Comment: Would your problem be that userList is not actually a list or users, but rather a JS object with a single property named InvoiceHeaders whose value is a list of users?

Comment: i am trying to use datatable example to my project.

Comment: Try setting $scope.userList = [ { "name" : "Tiger", ... }, { "name" : "Garret", .. } ]; ...

Comment: copy and paste your JSON code to https://jsonlint.com/, you should remove the trailing ; after ]

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is not valid , change it as,

```
{
  "InvoiceHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

DEMO

```js
var myApp = angular.module('testApp',[]);
myApp.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.userList = {
  "InvoiceHeaders": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<ul ng-repeat="user in userList.InvoiceHeaders">
   <li>{{user.name}}</li>
  <li>{{user.position}}</li>
  <li>{{user.office}}</li>
  <td>
 </ul>
</body>
```